# One to One unidirectional mapping with same primary key in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I have two classes/tables (Metafile and RowCount) with a one to one relation. Rowcount only applys to certain metafiles. Currently I have this set up (simplified):

## MetaFile.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "file")
public class MetaFile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "file_id")
    private int fileId;
    // getters, setters, constructors...
}
```

## RowCount.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "row_count")
public class RowCount implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="file_id")
    private MetaFile file;

    @Id
    @Column(name="file_id")
    private int file_id; // duplicate field needed so that crudrepo would recognise the id

    private int rows;

    public RowCount(MetaFile file, int rows) {
        this.file = file;
        this.rows = rows;
        this.file_id = file.getFileId();
    }
    // getters, setters...
}
```

I'm using crudrepositories for both to simplify persistance.

I first save the metafile to get an ID assigned, then I create a rowcount object using that metafile with the new ID and save it (shown below). This second save fails however, as the metafile isn't persisted to the database immediately, and the foreign key constraint fails.

```
metaFile = fileRepository.save(metaFile);

rowCountRepository.save(new RowCount(metaFile,getNumberOfRows(file));
```

The metaFile definitely gets a valid id assigned to it. Is there a way to make sure these two persists happen in order?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested it by 'PRIMARYJOINCOLUMN' or @mapsId annotation?

Comment: @HadiJ added Primary key join column to new RowCount field in MetaFile, and MapsId with JoinColumn to RowCount. However, on save I now get a null identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your mapping with `@mapsId` as suggested by Hadi J to have a single pk/fk column in `RowCount`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "row_count")
public class RowCount implements Serializable {

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "file_id")
   @MapsId
   private MetaFile file;

   @Id
   @Column(name="file_id")
   private int file_id;

   private int rows;

   public RowCount(MetaFile file, int rows) {
       this.file = file;
       this.rows = rows;
   }
   // getters, setters...

}
```

I would use a bidirectional relationship to simplify saving:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "file")
public class MetaFile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "file_id")
    private int fileId;
    // getters, setters, constructors...

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "file")
    private RowCount rowCount;
}
```

This way you can just set the relationship and save

```
RowCount rowCount = new RowCount(metaFile, getNumberOfRows(file));
metaFile.setRowCount(rowCount);
metaFile = fileRepository.save(metaFile);
```

Comment: Love it! It's almost working too. I'm using an existing schema with hibernate, and during schema validation I'm getting the error "missing column [file_file_id] in table [row_count]". Currently looking into why it's appending that file_ to the start.

Comment: I added @JoinColumn(name = "file_id") to the File field  in RowCount and that's moved it on.