# How to map one to one relation with no foreign key in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I have 2 entities with the following mapping

**FileContent.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FILE_CONTENT", schema="COMMON")
public class FileContent implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="ID")
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "FILE_ID")
  private File docFile; 

}
```

and **File.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FILE", schema="COMMON")
public class File implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="ID")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "FILE_NAME")
  private String fileName;  

}
```

So far this mapping is working fine as I can get **File** using fileContent.getDocFile().

So is it possible that I can map the **FileContent** within the **File** also?
I tried to add the mapping in this way but it's not working, I always getting null when I access using file.getFileContent();

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FILE", schema="COMMON")
public class File implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="ID")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "FILE_NAME")
  private String fileName;  

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "docFile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private FileContent fileContent;

}
```

I also tried with @MapsId and @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921243/one-to-one-unidirectional-mapping-with-same-primary-key-in-hibernate) but still not able to get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

===================================================================

**Edited on 8/8/2019**

Thanks for Razib for the answer, and it's working perfectly.
However I found that it's working when I select the `FILE` record form the DB, but not from a freshly saved `FILE` object.

```
File file = new File();
file.setFileName("sample.txt")
fileRepo.saveAndFlush(file);

File fileContent = new FileContent();
fileContent.set....;
fileContent.setFile(file);
fileContentRepo.saveAndFlush(fileContent);

return file;
```

I'm not using the `Cascade` to save these entities. When I access the return `file` using `file.getFileContent();` and it's **null**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is bidirectional one to one mapping. Now the mapping is done only one way. In bidirectional mapping, you need to put `File` reference in `FileContent` and vice versa. Check the following code snippet -

**File:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FILE", schema="COMMON")
public class File {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="ID")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "FILE_NAME")
        private String fileName;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "file", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
           fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        private FileContent details;  

        //constructors getters and setters

    }
```

**FileContent:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FILE_CONTENT", schema="COMMON")
public class FileContent{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FILE_NAME")
    private String fileName;  

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FILE_ID")
    private File file;   

    //constructors getters and setters
}
```

**Notes:**

- The above code snippet will create the table named `FILE_CONTENT` with a column named `FILE_ID`.
- `FILE_ID` is the foreign key referencing the primary key of `FILE.ID`.
- Here in the association, the `File` entity is the parent, while the `FileContent` is the child. Because the foreign key is located in the `FILE_CONTENT` table.
- Now from your code, you can access both entities from any side like - `file.getFileContent()` or `fileContent.getFile()`

Comment: Thanks Razib, your answer works perfectly, but I found another problem beside this, and I updated it on the question. Appreciate if you can have a look on it. Thanks.