# Hibernate one-to-one mapping with secondary table and without creating foreign key

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have two JPA entities : Ring and Principal

```
@Entity
class Ring {
   @Id
   int rId;
   String description;
}

@Entity
class Principal {
  @Id
  int pId;
  String description;
  String type;

  // ?? required annotations 
  Ring ring;
}
```

Though the **Principal to Ring relationship is one-to-one**, I have to maintain a separate table **principals_rings**.

DB schema looks like:

```
Ring   
-----------------     
rId | description     

Principal
-------------
pId | description | type

principals_rings
----------------
pId | rId
```

**I don't want to create any foreign keys** to table **principals_rings**.

How can I **join Principal table with principal_rings** with hibernate annotations ? I want to have the Ring object inside the Principal class.
I tried with @OneToOne mapping and @JoinTable() but both of them create foreign key on
principals_rings.

Comment: "I don't want to create any foreign keys to table principals_rings." <- Might I ask why? I don't think it is possible without foreign keys, because that is in the end what hibernate uses to build joins for its queries.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to have any constraints on principals_rings, it is just the requirement that I have. If the relationship was many-to-many, we can use ElementCollection and CollectionTable which does not enforce any constraints. I am just looking if we can have one-to-one relationship in the same way.

Comment: You can make rings transient and populate it separately, you can write a custom query that does the join and map the returned data manually.

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57390724/how-to-map-one-to-one-relation-with-no-foreign-key-in-jpa

Comment: You don't need foreign keys - If your provider is generating them, have it generate a script and manually remove them from the script. DDL generation in JPA is for development aid - I seriously hope you don't use it in production and at least check in scripts you can manually check, verify and edit with DBA assistance. Just be careful that your application carefully maintain that join table and you don't inadvertently let a concurrent modification go through that might add an entry in there while another process is deleting the referenced entity. FKs protect your application data!

Comment: What about many to many? I think you can use it, why not.